# reaching values in dictionary inside dictionary python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, lambda, nested, ordereddictionary

ok ill try to simplify this:

1st question: is a dictionary of dictionaries considered more appropriate than a list of dictionaries?

2nd Question: I'm struggling to reach the second level of my dictionaries to print them out in the right order.

I know dicts are not ordered, but I've managed to get lambda to order the first dictionary to get the notes printed out 1-10.

Now I need to get the second level to print out in the order they're written (ID & NAME before CONTENT).

Any help to get control over this would be much appreciated ;)

```
annotations = {}
index = 1
for i in range(10):
annotations['Annotation #: '+str(i+1)+" --->>"] = {
    'ID' : index,
    'NAME:' : 'Tag Name',
    'CONTENT:' : 'Note Content: This space will have a lot of text',
    'URL:' : 'ref address',
    'URL Info:' : 'url info',
}
index += 1

for key, values in sorted(annotations.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    print "\n"+key
    for k, v in sorted(values.items(), key = lambda item: item[1]):
        print k, v
```

outputs:

```
Annotation #: 1 --->>
ID 1
CONTENT: Note Content: This space will have a lot of text
NAME: Tag Name
URL: ref address
URL Info: url info

#....... etc.. to:

Annotation #: 10 --->>
ID 10
CONTENT: Note Content: This space will have a lot of text
NAME: Tag Name
URL: ref address
URL Info: url info
```

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish. Please clarify

Comment: @Bharel apologies I've tried to clean the question(s) up a bit. It was late and I had been bashing my head against this for a while. Basically i want to be able to print k, v in the right order.. or separately pair by pair. Does that make sense? thanks

Comment: What is the "right" order here? Currently you're using the values of each dictionary, which give a pretty arbitrary order (that happens to look nice with your test data only by chance). I suspect a list of `namedtuple` objects would be much more natural for what you're doing.

Comment: @Blckknght oh I was convinced that `sorted(annotations.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):` helped me get the the first level dict from 1-10. Is that not so?

Comment: @DavidFlamholc: It does so only by chance. Your inner dictionaries only differ by `ID` value, so that's what ends up getting compared. If you had different values for the other keys, you'd get fairly a more random order, I think. It would also not work in Python 3, where `dict` objects are not comparable at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to tightly control the order of the things in your container, I think using dictionaries is a bad idea. As you note, the items in a `dict` are ordered arbitrarily. Currently your code sorts them by value, but that's not very meaningful.

I think it would be much more natural to use a list for the top level container, since you're creating the objects in order and want to keep that order. The keys of your top level dictionary were pretty meaningless, and can be replaced by indexes (e.g the output of `enumerate`).

For the inner container objects, there are more options. You could use an `OrderedDict` (from the `collections` module in the standard library) instead of a regular `dict`. That would let you iterate over the `items` of the dictionary in the same order you added them. You'd need to avoid using a dictionary literal to define the object though, or the order would be lost before the items were in the `OrderedDict`.

Another good option might be to create your own type with the `namedtuple` type-factory (also from `collections`). The type you'd get would be a kind of `tuple` that allows attribute access for its members, in addition to indexing.

You could also write your own class, which handles its attributes however you want. You could write a `__str__` method that could turn the data into a string in whatever format you want.

As you requested in the comments, here's a quick and dirty implementation using a `list` of `OrderedDict`s:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

annotations = [OrderedDict([('ID', i + 1),     # need to initialize with a list of tuples
                            ('NAME', 'Tag Name'),   # to preserve the order of the items
                            ('CONTENT', 'Note Content: This space will have a lot of text'),
                            ('URL', 'ref address'),
                            ('URL Info', 'url info')])
               for i in range(10)]

for i, dct in enumerate(annotations):
    print("Annotation #{}".format(i+1))
    for key, value in dct.items():
        print("{}: {}".format(key, value))
    print()
```

I created all the annotations in a list comprehension here. When you're generating your real data with non-dummy data, you might not be able to do that as easily, but it should work just as well if you write out a regular `for` loop and `append` the `OrderedDict`s to it.

Comment: thanks again @Blckknght for the info and explanation. Needless to say I'm a beginner; any chance for a small example of how I could set up using a list of OrderedDicts? I've been reading up on all the stuff you wrote but I'm a bit cross-eyed at this point

Comment: and again thanks! @Blckknght for this! sorry for having been so blunt as to ask for this straight up but it's really making more sense to me than I had even hoped. I'll try to go through it on my computer first thing in the morning ;)